# Failure delivering result?

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

first of all I'm new to Android design so help me out please.
I am trying to configure two Activities, first one displays Trips in a list, the second is used to fill out a formal by the user to define the Trip. However, when I click the creation button on my second activity I get the Failure Delivering Result with a NullPointerException, any idea to why?

Here is my MainActivity, onClick of Add it executed startActivityForResult();

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final int TRIP_CREATE=100;
    private TripsData datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    datasource=new TripsData(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Trip> values=datasource.getAllTrips();

    ArrayAdapter<Trip> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Trip>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Will be called via the onClick attribute
  // of the buttons in main.xml
  public void onClick(View view) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter<Trip> adapter=(ArrayAdapter<Trip>) getListAdapter();
    Trip trip=null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent nextScreen=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TripCreateActivity.class);
        // starting new activity
        startActivityForResult(nextScreen, TRIP_CREATE);
      break;

    case R.id.delete:
        if (getListAdapter().getCount()> 0) {
            trip=(Trip) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
            datasource.deleteTrip(trip);
            adapter.remove(trip);
        }
      break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
  }
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
      ArrayAdapter<Trip> adapter=(ArrayAdapter<Trip>) getListAdapter();

      if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {

             if(requestCode==TRIP_CREATE){      
                 //String result=data.getStringExtra("name");  
                 Trip trip=datasource.createTrip(data.getStringExtra("name"), 
                         data.getStringExtra("type"));
                 adapter.add(trip);
             }
             if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED) {    
                 //Write your code if there's no result
             }
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  }
```

}

And this is the activity that fills out the Trip information, I do not think that the issue is here though:

```
public class TripCreateActivity extends Activity {
    protected static final int TRIP_CREATE=100;
    private TripsData datasource;
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trip_create);

    datasource=new TripsData(this);
    datasource.open();

    inputName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputType=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.type);
    Button Finish=(Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);
    Finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            //Intent nextScreen=new Intent();

            //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());
            nextScreen.putExtra("type", inputType.getText().toString());
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, nextScreen);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Create button: "+inputName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();
            //startActivity(nextScreen);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.trip_create, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the TripsData code, I am new to databases so I think the error is somewhere here:

```
public class TripsData {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private TripsDB dbHelper;
private String[] allTrips = { TripsDB.TRIP_COLUMN_ID,
        TripsDB.TRIP_COLUMN_TYPE};

public TripsData(Context context){
    dbHelper = new TripsDB(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException{
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}

public Trip createTrip(String name, String type){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TripsDB.TRIP_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(TripsDB.TRIP_COLUMN_TYPE, type);
    long insertId = database.insert(TripsDB.TABLE_TRIPS, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TripsDB.TABLE_TRIPS, 
            allTrips, TripsDB.TRIP_COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Trip newTrip = cursorToTrip(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newTrip;
}

public void deleteTrip(Trip trip){
    long id = trip.getId();
    System.out.println("Project deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(TripsDB.TABLE_TRIPS, TripsDB.TRIP_COLUMN_ID
            + " = " + id, null);
}

public List<Trip> getAllTrips(){
    List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<Trip>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(TripsDB.TABLE_TRIPS,
            allTrips, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        Trip trip = cursorToTrip(cursor);
        trips.add(trip);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return trips;
}

private Trip cursorToTrip(Cursor cursor){
    Trip trip = new Trip();
    trip.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    trip.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    return trip;
}
```

Logcat:

```
    02-22 12:20:37.251: I/name =(5947): Hard coded Name
02-22 12:20:37.251: I/type=(5947): Hard code Type
02-22 12:20:37.251: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(5947): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table trips has no column named name, db=/data/data/com.example.festivent/databases/trips.db
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947): Error inserting name=Hard coded Name
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table trips has no column named name: , while compiling: INSERT INTO trips(name) VALUES (?)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at com.example.merptivity.TripsData.createTrip(TripsData.java:37)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at com.example.merptivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-22 12:20:37.272: E/SQLiteDatabase(5947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 12:20:37.272: D/AndroidRuntime(5947): Shutting down VM
02-22 12:20:37.272: W/dalvikvm(5947): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.festivent/com.example.merptivity.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:434)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at com.example.merptivity.TripsData.cursorToTrip(TripsData.java:71)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at com.example.merptivity.TripsData.createTrip(TripsData.java:41)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at com.example.merptivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-22 12:20:37.292: E/AndroidRuntime(5947):     ... 11 more
```

**EDIT**
Here is my datatable:

```
public static abstract class TRIP implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "trips";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "_type";
    public static final String COLUMN_COST = "cost";
    public static final String COLUMN_START = "start";
    public static final String COLUMN_END = "end";
    public static final String SQL_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
                    + "(" + TRIP._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " 
                    + COLUMN_TYPE
                    + " text);";
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat ?

Comment: please tell me what is the code at TripsData.java at line  35 ?

Comment: I tweaked the code a little bit so I dont know the exact line you are refering to but my guess would be inside createTrip()? I am trying to move the input contents inside the database.

Comment: run the application again and get the new logcat , post it here and i will tell you what line of code i need

Comment: ok, just updated the logcat output

Comment: ok line 35 ?  TripsData ?

Comment: long insertId = database.insert(TripsDB.TABLE_TRIPS, null, values);

Comment: please add this code before the line 35 :
Log.i("name =",name);
Log.i("type=",type);
and post the updated logcat please

Comment: posted, its telling me that i don't have a column name? but it is clearly there, i can post my database code too if you want

Comment: please post your create table statement ?

Comment: there is no column name  ?